# How to display grid from xml parameter using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

This is my requirement

1) A service call is made to fetch data in JSON format.

2) Service result contains many data fields, which need to be displayed in DataGrid view.

3) Next , I have  XML file, which is just like configuration file. In this xml file, I have defined which column need to displayed**(Visible or Not visible)**, what kind of data filed the column should use to render data. Basically this xml file defines Column properties for datagrid.

Eg:

```
<Columns>
        <Column name="cloumn1" visible="true" />
       <Column name="cloumn2" visible="true" />
 </Columns>
```

---

Please guide me, what approach should I follow and what is best Jquery datagrid API for this.

Thank u all!